# Class typed Rest Parameters is treated like any from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, args

I'm trying to migrate my formal Javascript project to Typescript, and met very weird thing.

```
class A { }

function a(i: number, ...args: A[]): void {
    console.log(i, args);
}

const b = new A();
const c = [new A(), new A(), new A()];

a(0, 45);
a(1, c);
a(2, b, b, b);
```

this is the simplication of the part of my code, there is class named 'A' and function 'a' requires a number type index and amount of instances of class 'A'.

in my expectation, this code should have to make an error. because 45 is number, and c is an array.

but it works.

it prints this to console

```
0 [ 45 ]
1 [ [ A {}, A {}, A {} ] ]
2 [ A {}, A {}, A {} ]
```

what am i missing? is it runtime bug? (I'm using deno as javascript/typescript runtime)
or, is there some reason Typescript allow this?

I'm new to Typescript, so I need some advice for this.

Comment: In your example, A is an empty class, which is not a very useful thing to do. Does it continue to misbehave if you add properties to A?

Comment: Or can you use an interface or type instead of a class? https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jcatbe

Comment: @NicholasTower Thank you very much. with some properties, compiler works fine. but I still feel weirdness because if the existence of properties is matter, It means typescript doesn't separate types of classes which has same data structure, and then, it may cause some errors. I worry about...  you know, sometimes there need some 'types' even it does not contain any useful, meaning datas

Comment: `It means typescript doesn't separate types of classes which has same data structure` That's completely correct. Typescript does structural typing, not nominal typing. There are some conversations about adding nominal typing in the future, and some hacky workarounds exist to mimic nominal types, but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since A is an empty class, the only properties it will have are the properties that all objects have; things like `.toString` or `.valueOf`. `number`s also have all of these same properties, and so do arrays, so what you're passing in *does* match what you've asked for.

As soon as you add properties to A, this issue will go away. For example, if you add an `id: string` property, then now neither numbers nor arrays will match, since they don't have such a property.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oChpugSwCYC5oQBcAnDAOwHNoBeaAcgEZaBuZAX2Q4DMBXU4AjAHtS0MAAoMeUtwC2AIwCmRADTQAdBrBFyEPLADaAXQCUeAG6DsiVOi079ABkNqCggMrEy5McZbpowMIQgiAKaiCC3hiqdhC+bByBpITQctTQpAoA7nA+LEkpwOn6mTmwPqqlucaV2dWGLMjiDqoALACs8eL0qsBdYgBMqnLDw75AA)